Even though I provide login credentials for the Play Console tester, I still get rejected
Even though I provide login credentials for the Play Console tester, I still get rejected.
I tried it in Firebase TestLab and it was successful there. In my application, I have login with Email & Password and Google Account. I provided all the information.


I provided all the information, but don't work
